Evaluation of $ \sum^{19}_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}\bigg(\frac{209\binom{18}{k-1}-\binom{20}{k}}{\binom{20}{k}\binom{19}{k}}\bigg)$

Evaluation of


$\displaystyle \sum^{19}_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}\bigg(\frac{209\binom{18}{k-1}-\binom{20}{k}}{\binom{20}{k}\binom{19}{k}}\bigg)$

What I try : $\displaystyle 209\sum^{19}_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\frac{18}{k-1}}{\binom{20}{k}\cdot \frac{19}{k}\cdot \frac{18}{k-1}}-\sum^{19}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\binom{19}{k}}$
$\displaystyle =11\sum^{19}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}k}{\binom{20}{k}}-\sum^{19}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\binom{19}{k}}$
I have seems that it should be in the form of Telescopic Sum.
But I did not understand how can I convert it, Help me please , Thanks

For $n$ being odd,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}=1$$
$$\color{blue}{\implies\sum_{k=1}^{19} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\binom{19}{k}}=1\tag1}$$

$$\color{green}{\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}k}{\binom{2n}{k}}=\frac{n}{n+1}\tag2}$$
Refer here

$$\color{black}{S=11S_1-S_2\tag3}$$
$$S =11\sum^{19}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}k}{\binom{20}{k}}-\sum^{19}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\binom{19}{k}}$$
Using $(1),(2)$ in $(3)$,
$$S=11\underset{n=10}{\underbrace{\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)}}-1$$
$$\boxed{S=9}$$
Checks out with this
